# Run Go script inside Docker Container or cron job?

Tags: go, cron, docker

I have Go application deployed over Docker. Other than running the main program, I want to run periodic job for updating my data.

Which is better?

1. Run periodic job using concurrency (channel) while being run on main program.
2. Crontab to register periodic job on system. But I don't know how to do this inside `Docker`

In Dockerfile or in docker what is the best way to run a separate cronjob?

Please help me. Thanks!

Comment: yeah, cron in docker as a separate container can be a bit tricky. It's often the point I break with microservices mantra of 1 proc / container

Answer (score 0):

If you are developing the application and all you need is basic periodical execution of one "job" , I would go and implement it in your app. If things get more complicated I would build on an image such as https://github.com/phusion/baseimage-docker which brings support for management of multiple container processes (including cron).